# Java OOP in MVC Legacy

Tags: java, oop, legacy

My question, overall, is in regards to best practices and efficiency. Today, my teacher and I had a discussion about OOP  in MVC Legacy. We were going through a previous project of mine and the question is "What's the point?"
The way my project (and all my projects) are structured, it doesn't make sense to me. Here is an example followed by my code.

**Controller**- Gets the String values from the form/View and passes them to the Service class. Single Responsibility would state that this is all it is responsible for, not creating an object to pass, but creating a < Map < String,Object >> would be totally fine from my understanding.

**Service Class**- Following best practices/single responsibility these methods are not supposed to do anything other than call the requested method/pass values.

**DAO**- The DAO is supposed to be responsible for transferring all data/objects into usable form for the D.B accessor and to return them as such.

But why build an object just to tear it down? Especially when you could just pass a list of values down as a  Map< String,Object > so all the values and columns match up?

The following are code snippets to help illustrate my question:

**Service Class:**

```
 public class ClientService {

      private Client_SQL_DAO_Strategy dao;

      public ClientService(Client_SQL_DAO_Strategy dao){
           setDaoStrategy(dao);
      }

      public void sendClientToStorage(Client client) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        dao.sendClientToDatabase(client);
      }

      public void updateClient(List values) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
       dao.updateClient(values);
      }
 }
```

**DAO**

```
 public void saveClient(Client client) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    List columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add("Last_Name");
    columns.add("First_Name");
    columns.add("Business_Name");
    columns.add("Phone");

    List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(client.getClientLastName());
    values.add(client.getClientFirstName());
    values.add(client.getClientBusiness());
    values.add(client.getClientPhone());

    accessor.createRecord(TABLE_NAME, columns, values);
}

public void updateClient(List listOfValues) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    List<Object> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add("Last_Name");
    columns.add("First_Name");
    columns.add("Business_Name");
    columns.add("Phone");

    int primaryKey = Integer.valueOf(listOfValues.get(0).toString());

        accessor.updateRecord(TABLE_NAME, columns, listOfValues, PK_COLUMN, primaryKey);

}
```

Comparing the two methods provided in the DAO which approach makes more sense? Creating the Client to tear it down or passing associated values and columns to the accessor? This  Map< String,Object > seems ideal for both methods.

And yes, I'm aware of the newer techniques as well, but at the current time in the semester Legacy is the lesson of the week.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by 'legacy'?  Do you mean legacy as in not using an ORM?

Comment: @jrahhali I probably used the wrong term and have a very loose understanding of ORM. My understanding of Object Relational Mapping is an OOP technique used to convert data between two systems that use similar but also different data types such as the way java stores a date vs the way the database stores a date. And since this is an older technique I guess 'legacy,' in the sense I used it, would mean "Old-school programming technique."

Comment: The question isn't so much about that is it is comparing the two methods in the DAO I provided. The question is, Why build an object only to tear it down in a DAO?

Comment: The short answer to your question is that you're learning how to structure a large scale OOP system with hundreds of database tables and thousands of web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC implements the [Model-View-Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) design pattern.

The responsibility of the Controller is to obtain/create/populate the Model and prepare the environment for the View.

The View is responsible for displaying Model data, in Spring MVC usually through JSP, but you can also specify View classes which do things like render Excel or PDF, for example.

The Model implements the domain logic. Depending on your implementation, this could be a "view model" containing only logic for the front end, or it can contain the real business rules. It should be a real class. Do not EVER use `Map<String, Object>`. Such usage of maps sacrifices type safety and is not OOP.

The Service class is like a controller class for external service coordination, like persistence, email, payment, etc.

The DAO class is a service provider just for persistence. It translates the object representation to database operations. This layer can be replaced by an ORM. Do not pass around `Map<String, Object>`!

If the only external service used by your app is persistence, you can avoid separate Service and DAO classes, and defer separation until you require more services.

For more information about this type of object modeling, check out [Domain Driven Design](http://blog.mirkosertic.de/architecturedesign/dddbuildingblocks).